# Good practice for branching on try/except

Tags: python, try-catch

Suppose my python code branches based on the result of a try/except as follows:

```
def(x):
    no_errors = False
    try:
        y = f(x)
        no_errors = True
    except ZError:
        no_errors = False
    if no_errors:
        do_stuff(y)
    else:
        do_other_stuff(x)
```

My linter warns that y may be undefined. Is this poor practice? What is the recommended fix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically, you wouldn't have code structured like this. You'd have `else` and/or `finally` clauses in the `try` statement.

```
def f(x):
    try:
        y = f(x)
    except ZError:
        do_other_stuff(x)
    else:
        do_stuff(y)
```

Answer (score 0):

`y` will be undefined if `y = f(x)` throws any kind of exception that is not a `ZError`. Technically, the variable `no_errors` really means "no `ZError`s". You could handle this more elegantly using an `else` or `finally` block to define `y`.

For example:

```
def(x):
    no_errors = false
    try:
        y = f(x)
        no_errors = True
    except ZError:
        no_errors = False
    finally:
        y = some_default
    if no_errors:
        do_stuff(y)
    else:
        do_other_stuff(x)
```

Also, the bool is not needed, since you can simply leverage the conditional nature of the try / except blocks (see chepner's answer)